# В чем ошибка PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

```
<?php

$url = $_POST["uploadUrl"]
$post_data = $_POST["photo"]

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
print_r($result);
?>
```

когда отправляю запрос на этот php получаю ошибку 500
в php я практический вообще не разбираюсь
помогите пожалйуста
на этот файл передается пост запрс с параметрами uploadUrl и photo в формате multipart/form-data 
нужно чтобы photo отправлялось на uploadUrl и респонс должен выводится

на этот php файл запрос отправляется с помощью этого скрипта

```
function requestUpload(){
  var formData = new FormData(document.photo);
  formData.append("uploadUrl", uploadUrl);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
  xhr.send(formData);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText)
       }
    };
}
```

но response никак не возвращается на alert

Comment: Прошу прощения за некорректный вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первых двух строках видна ошибка. После них должна быть точка с запятой.

```
$url = $_POST["uploadUrl"];
$post_data = $_POST["photo"];
```

Comment: извините не подскажете как получить $result как респонс

Comment: function requestUpload(){
  var formData = new FormData(document.photo);
  formData.append("uploadUrl", uploadUrl);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
  xhr.send(formData);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText)
       }
    };
}

Comment: @БагдаулетСайын Извините я не понял ваш вопрос ? Все это нормально опишите в вопросе .

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jufosajuwe/edit?js
 вот upload.php это код в вопросе  после выполнения он должен print_r($result);
как вот этот result получить на js

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: @БагдаулетСайын Вы же делаете запрос `ajax` на этот код. Там сделайте `return $result`. и он вернет все это в запрос. В место `print_r($result)`.

Comment: я этот php с интернета взял точнее вот отсюда http://codly.ru/snippets/165/

не подскажете что делает это строка
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

так как если я добвляю в конце
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);

в resonse возвращается null

без него вообще ничего не возвращается

Comment: @БагдаулетСайын оно делает запрос `curl` потом декодирует пришетший `json`. и еще что бы понять откуда ошибка, просто сдeлайте `echo 'Какой то string';` и посмотрите это идет на `js`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72538/discussion-between---and-raz-galstyan).